# diesel.rs: Trying to update a column with a composite primary key

Tags: database, rust, orm, rust-diesel

I am struggling to find a way to update a column.
This column has a composite primary key.

I've tried something like:

```rs
    for anime_ranking in new_anime_rankings {
        let mut db_anime_ranking: models::AnimeRanking = anime_rankings
            .find((anime_ranking.id, anime_ranking.genre_combo_id))
            .first(&mut connection)?;
        println!("{}", db_anime_ranking.id);

        db_anime_ranking.times_watched += 1; // directly increment it by 1 as anime_ranking.times_watched is always 1
        update(anime_rankings.filter((id.eq(anime_ranking.id), genre_combo_id.eq(anime_ranking.genre_combo_id))))
            .set(times_watched.eq(db_anime_ranking.times_watched += 1))
            .execute(&mut connection)?;
    }
```

Though it does not work. I can't find anything about it in the docs as well.
Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Found it.
You have to use .and():

```rs
update(anime_rankings.filter(id.eq(anime_ranking.id).and(genre_combo_id.eq(anime_ranking.genre_combo_id)))
```